# An error occurs when adding InMobi in AdMob Mediation

Tags: iphone, ios, inmobi

The following error will appear when I add in InMobi iOS:

> > `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[IMAdView initWithFrame:imAppId:imAdUnit:rootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb9e2080'`

I have the following:

・ AdMob Mediation SDK add
 ・ InMobi adapter and SDK add
 ・ Other Linker Flags add -ObjC and -all_load**

Still missing something? Do you need or import?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't calling this method on a proper `IMAdView` object.  As per [the documentation](http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=MoPub_InMobi_iOS), this works:

```
IMAdView *someAdView = [[IMAdView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50) imAppId:@"YOUR_INMOBI_APP_ID" imAdSize:IM_UNIT_320x50 rootViewController:self];
```

You have to allocate an object with `alloc` before initializing it.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I think the above is seen as the implementation of a custom event, and supports the standard "InMobi" in "AdMob Mediation". Will do as a custom event implementation?

Comment: @user1785325 Not sure what you mean. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too, when I updated my Google AdMob SDK to ver 6.4.2, and the InMobiAdMobiOSAdapter, to whatever the latest version is, but neglected to update the inMobi SDK to 3.7.0.

On this page: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks look at the row for InMobi. You have to download both the adapter("adapter for iOS") and the SDK ("Download iOS"), and incorporate them into your project.